# System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Bad Hash

Tags: sql-server-ce-3.5

I have an application that connects to an SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 database. The application will randomly fail, throwing a SqlCeException with the message "bad hash." What is causing this exception and how can I prevent it? I can't find any information on google that might explain what's going on. The problem seems to be fixable with a reboot, but I would like to know more about what causes it and how to prevent it.

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Bad Hash.
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
```

Comment: What version (build) of SQL  CE 3.5 do you use?

Comment: Is your applicaion using multiple threads? And do you act accordingly (not share objects across threads) ?

Comment: The application is single-threaded.

Comment: Suggest you improve your error handling and also share your connection string https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/af796258b5ffe94b63a25687979f5d16d7d76ba8/src/API/Generator/Helper.cs#L302

Comment: Data Source=EDT.sdf;Max Database Size=4091;Password=the password to the database

Comment: What OS and Service Pack?

Comment: Windows 7 Service Pack 1. I took your advice and added more detailed messages for SqlCeExceptions to the application error log. Haven't seen the bug pop up a gain in a while.